# Update table results, based on checkbox selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I have a page in which i am displaying a set of results from a MySQL database and displaying it in a datatable. I wish to be able to select different options with checkboxes, and update the results accordingly.

I have created the checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filter_products" class='form-control filter_products' id='show_zeros' value="Zeroes"> Show Zeroes<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter_products" id='show_all' value="All"> Show all products<br>
```

And then I am including a separate php file which runs the MySQL query and creates the table based on the results

```
include ('load_table.php');
```

I have tried to do it with an AJAX call

```
$('input').on('ifClicked', function(event)
    {
        if ($('#show_zeros').prop('checked'))
            var show_zeros = $('#show_zeros').val();

        if ($('#show_all').prop('checked'))
            var show_all = $('#show_all').val();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "load_table.php",
            data: {'show_zeros' : show_zeros, 'show_all' : show_all},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {

            },
                error: function() {}

            }); 
    });
```

but I don't seem to be getting any results. In fact, it doesn't look like the show_zeros and show_all variables are getting passed as when I try

```
$show_zeroes = $_POST['show_zeros'];
$show_all = $_POST['show_all'];
echo 'Show zeroes: ' . $show_zeroes;
echo 'Show All: ' . $show_all;
```

I get empty strings.

Further on in the code, I have the following code to manipulate the query for MySQL.

```
if ($show_zeroes == 'Zeroes' && $show_all == 'undefined') {
  $query = "select sp.product_id AS product_id, sp.department_id AS department_id, 
              sp.product_name AS product_name, sd.department_name AS department_name, 
              sp.unit_cost AS unit_cost, SUM(sp.quantity_units) AS quantity_counted, 
            ROUND(SUM(sp.quantity_units) * sp.unit_cost,2) AS total_cost 
            FROM stocktake_details sp 
              INNER JOIN store_departments sd 
              ON sd.id = sp.department_id 
            WHERE sp.stocktake_id = $stocktake_id 
            GROUP BY sp.product_id ORDER BY total_cost DESC";
} else if ($show_zeroes == 'Zeroes' && $show_all == 'All') {
  $query = "SELECT sp.product_id AS product_id, sp.department_id AS department_id, 
              sp.product_name AS product_name, sd.department_name AS department_name, 
              sp.unit_cost AS unit_cost, SUM(sp.quantity_units) AS quantity_counted, 
            ROUND(SUM(sp.quantity_units) * sp.unit_cost,2) AS total_cost 
            FROM stocktake_details sp 
              INNER JOIN store_departments sd 
              ON sd.id = sp.department_id 
            WHERE sp.stocktake_id = $stocktake_id 
            GROUP BY sp.product_id ORDER BY total_cost DESC";
} else {
  $query = "SELECT sp.product_id AS product_id, sp.department_id AS department_id, 
              sp.product_name AS product_name, sd.department_name AS department_name, 
              sp.unit_cost AS unit_cost, SUM(sp.quantity_units) AS quantity_counted, 
            ROUND(SUM(sp.quantity_units) * sp.unit_cost,2) AS total_cost 
            FROM stocktake_details sp 
              INNER JOIN store_departments sd 
              ON sd.id = sp.department_id 
            WHERE sp.stocktake_id = $stocktake_id AND sp.quantity_units > 0 
            GROUP BY sp.product_id ORDER BY total_cost DESC"; }
```

Am I on the right track with what I am trying to achieve, and if so, where am I going wrong?

Thank you.